# Android system throwing ErrnoException (2) before my launcher activity runs

Tags: java, android, debugging, exception

I've started having this weird issue where the code would run normally in 'Run', but any sort of debugging would cause the device to throw an ErrnoException with **errno = 2**. I haven't been able to find what errno 2 means. **My code here is irrelevant, since even the first line of code isn't reached.** Attached is a picture of my stack trace. Notice how "Variable debug info [is] not available", and "this" is not shown in the var list.

[image: This is thrown before any code of mine is run]

If this actually helps anyone:

[image: Doubt this is actually useful]

Let me know what you need, I'll get back to you quickly, and thanks in advance!

EDIT 1: Logcat verbose during exception
**NOTE: package name is blurred**

[image]

Comment: post your code...

Comment: What code should I post? Haven't I made it clear that my code is not even run when this exception is thrown?

Comment: am asking source code of this file

Comment: Sorry, source code of which file? The exception?

Comment: which file you get exception? post that file code

Comment: The problem is, i have no idea where the exception is happening

Comment: put your logcat verbose code here from first that you run the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine that you figured this out a while ago, but let's get the answer in here for others reading this...

You are probably set up to break on all exceptions.  This is a normal exception thrown by some part of the Android launching system.  If you continue past it, the Exception will be caught by Android and your app will launch as usual.